# How to show the name of the item you're holding out of the inventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

How do you show the name of the item you're holding out of the inventory (in the hotbar)?

Comment: Does it not appear when switching items?

Comment: Nope It Doesn't Appear. I Don't Know Why :(

Comment: What version are you on? Are you using OptiFine?

Comment: 1.18.1 and 1.8.9 and yep i'm using optifine

Comment: I've had that bug in 1.8 OptiFine before. Sometimes you can fix it by turning on Held Item Tooltips in Video Settings -> Details.

Comment: ayo that worked thx :)

Comment: **Not** technical support of modded Minecraft, because this is not a technical issue.

Comment: @MrParrot you should post an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item name should show when switching items. It may not show in older versions of the game, but it modern versions this is a feature.

If it doesn't this is usually due to your OptiFine settings.

If you are using OptiFine, here is how to re-enable the this feature:

[image: Video Settings, Details and Held Item Tooltips]